# problem when use withCount and cursorPaginate together in laravel

Tags: laravel, count, pagination

I have two tables :

`profiles` table

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | title | verify |
+----+-------+--------+
```

And `profile_followers` table

```
+------------+---------+
| profile_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
```

I want to get profile list with `orderBy` count followers together `cursorPaginate` in Laravel

I use this code :

```
$profile = Profile::where('verify', '=', 1)
    ->withCount('followers')
    ->orderBy('followers_count', 'desc')
    ->cursorPaginate(20);
```

I get the first 20 rows, but when I try to return the next 20 rows with `Cursor(nextPageUrl)`, an error like this occurs:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'followers_count' in 'where clause'

It works with `Paginate`, but not with `cursorPaginate`.